# Exception in thread main java.lang.ΝullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hello im making a programm and when i run it,it shows me this message:exception in thread main java.lang.nullpointerexception
at FileReader.readfile(TestFiles.java:53)
at TestFiles.main(TestFiles.java:240)

So here is where the problem seems to be in my programm

```
class FileReader
{
 private String path;
 private File object;
 private Scanner inputReader;
 private String Line;
 public FileReader(String path)
 {
    this.path=path;

 }
 public boolean initReader()
 {

   object = new File(path);

   Scanner inputReader = null;

    try
    {
        inputReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("universities.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File universities.txt was not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (object.exists())
    {
        return true;

    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> readFile()
{   
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();


        while(inputReader.hasNextLine()); //here is the line:53
            myList.add(Line);

        myList.remove(0);   

        return myList;
}
public void closeReader()
{
    inputReader.close();
}
```

}

and the main is here

```
public class TestFiles 
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("universities.txt");
        if(reader.initReader()){
            FileEditor editor = new FileEditor(reader.readFile()); //here is the line 240
            reader.closeReader();
            editor.fillHashMap();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("universities_2015_output.txt");
            if(writer.initWriter()){
                writer.writeFile(editor.getScoresOfYear(2015));
                writer.closeWriter();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error creating file");
        }
        System.out.println("Average university score of year 2015: "+editor.getAverageOfYear(2015));
        System.out.println("Min university score of year 2015: "+editor.getMinOfYear(2015));
        System.out.println("Max university score of year 2015: "+editor.getMaxOfYear(2015));
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
    }
}
```

}

i already read for this problem and i think that my problem is  on the inputreader which shows null. Any idea will be helpfull.I must complete this programm in this week so i need your help to finish it.
Thank you

Comment: Do you parse somewhere String Line to add it then to the ArrayList ?

Comment: i initialize it as private String Line;
What else should i do?

Comment: Try , private String Line = "";

Comment: Thanks, now it passes from compiler but when i type java TestFiles to run it doesnt do anything.Any idea for this?

Comment: Maybe Line is like the whole text and removed by myList.remove(0);. Why you remove index 0 in the while loop ? You may include also some System.out.println("okay"); or to check the contents of ArrayLists, in parts that should be executed, to debug your program.

Comment: i want to remove the first line